# VBScript String Manipulation

Tags: string, vbscript

I have the below file:

forgeversion.properties, inside is the below content.

```
forge.major.number=4
forge.minor.number=3
forge.revision.number=5
forge.build.number=318
```

I wish to grab the numbers at the end, and then combine them into a format such as:

```
4.3.5.318
```

Just to be more clear, I would like to parse the above data and grab from it the numbers, arranging them into the above new string.

I have already obtained the contents of the file into a variable, ReadVersion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with a regex method of obtaining the numbers and then creating the string.

```
        Set oRE = New Regexp
        With oRE
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = "=(\d+)"
        End With

        Set colMatches = oRE.Execute ( ReadVersion )
        For Each oMatch In colMatches
            ReDim Preserve arrMatches(lngCount)
            arrMatches(lngCount) = oMatch.SubMatches(0)
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
        Next

        ForgeVer = arrMatches(0) & "." & arrMatches(1) & "." & arrMatches(2) & "." & arrMatches(3)
```

Outputs in this case: 4.3.5.318

Answer (score 1):

You use [`CStr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk841e9(v=vs.84).aspx) to convert other data to string. To concatenate the various string parts, use the `&` operator.

```
Dim versionString

versionString = CStr(forge.major.number) & "." & CStr(forge.minor.number) & _
    "." & CStr(forge.revision.number) & "." & CStr(forge.build.number)
```

Comment: Apologies, I am unsure on how to interface that code, I currently have read the file into the variable ForgeVersion. How do I apply the above code to that variable?

Comment: Thinking about it, it looks like you believe the content of the file are already variables, they are not, just text. I want to extract the numbers from the file to create 4.3.5.318.